# Is there a Vulkan equivalent to OpenGL's pixel buffer object?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

I did some Googling and it does not appear that Vulkan has a Pixel Buffer Object. Is there something analogous to it in the Vulkan API?

Comment: PBO are for async pixel transfers right? That's instead in the transfer operations and the async nature of the queues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenGL doesn't "have a Pixel Buffer Object" either. What OpenGL has is *memory*, aka: [buffer objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object). One of the uses of buffer objects is as the source/destination for [pixel transfer operations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer); when used with buffer objects, they [can execute asynchronously](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object). While doing this is commonly called "pixel buffer objects", it's not a special object. It's just using OpenGL-allocated memory to perform an asynchronous copy of image data into/outof a buffer object.

OpenGL needs a special system for that because it is inherently a synchronous API. By contrast, almost *nothing* in Vulkan is synchronous. So Vulkan doesn't need a special system for doing it.

`vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` is a Vulkan command, as identified because it starts with `vkCmd`. As such, it is not executed immediately; such commands are stored in Vulkan command buffers, to be executed by the GPU asynchronously.

Vulkan doesn't have a special system for doing asynchronous pixel copies because Vulkan operations are *by default* asynchronous. And unlike OpenGL, it will not try to hide this from you.